# Character Encoding for ISO8583

Tags: financial, banking, iso8583

i use **Apache Mina** for TCP/IP Communication for *ISO8583 Message*.
But i wonder, what the character encoding for the message? Just send standard **String** or **bytes**?

Answer (score 2):

The type of message encoding is going to depend on the ISO8583 Message Spec of the processor/bank in which you are sending to.

From your code you will likely send an array of bytes vs a string due to the binary nature of ISO8583, its bitmap, and field types.

Some interfaces will use ASCII, others EBCDIC - Extended Binary Coded Decimal Interchange Code , some values will be Binary Coded Decimal ('BCD') - The ISO8583 Message spec and if you can get ahold of any sample traces or samples messages will assist you.